# Writing a JSON serialization function

Tags: json, swift

I'd like to make a function that takes in a few parameters and then outputs the data I need from a web API. Obviously a good deal of the time I'll need to customize it to suit the use case but just for fun I'm trying to figure out a super basic function the successfully parses JSON, as about half of the lines of code in the function below are generic error handling.

For example if I generally use something like

```
func getJSON(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            print(err!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let response = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)

            self.storyData = response.results

            completionHandler(true)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

The only three things that will change from case to case (again, in the most absolutely basic of scenarios) are the url link to the API, the Struct that I set up to look for the pieces of data I need, and the array that I output the results to once the data request is finished.

Could I trim the fat on that and do something like

```
func jsonFetcher(apiLink: String, structToDecode: String, arrayThatHoldsResponse: [String], completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let jsonUrlString = apiLink
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            print(err!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let response = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(structToDecode, from: data)

            arrayThatHoldsResponse = response.results

            completionHandler(true)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I'm just not sure about the data types of `structToDecode` and `arrayThatHoldsResponse` (in the example function above I just using `String` as a placeholder), assuming they look like

**Struct(s)**

```
struct TopStoriesResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let results: [Story]
}

struct Story: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
    let url: String
    let multimedia: [Multimedia]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case abstract
        case url
        case multimedia
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        abstract = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .abstract)
        url = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
        multimedia = (try? container.decode([Multimedia].self, forKey: .multimedia)) ?? []
    }

}
```

**Array**

```
var storyData = [Story]()
```

**This way I can just call**

```
jsonFetcher(apiLink: link, structToDecode: myStruct, arrayThatHoldsResponse: myArray, completionHandler: <#T##(Bool) -> ()#>)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are partly correct. Although the arrayThatHoldsResponse should also be a closure parameter so that it could be used at the place you would call the jsonFetcher method. Also instead of passing the struct as string you could just pass the struct's type using type(of:) method. EDIT: arrayThatHoldsResponse will be of type [Story]

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question - in the example `jsonFetcher` function I just used `String` as a placeholder. And I don't think I can set `arrayThatHoldsResponse` to be of type [myStruct] in the function signature because I'd have to set it as `[Whatever the name of myStruct is]`, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power of generics. You can make a generic function, where the parameter is the `urlString`. The `T` inheritance the `Decodable` protocol.

This way you can call this function everytime as long as your Model inheritance the `Decodable` protocol.

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(object)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Failed to decode json:", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

**How to call the function:**

```
struct User: Decodable { }

fetchData(urlString: "yourUrl") { (User: User) in
    // Handle result
}


struct Animal: Decodable { }

fetchData(urlString: "yourUrl") { (animal: Animal) in
    // Handle result
}


// Or if you want to fetch an array of users instead
fetchData(urlString: "yourUrl") { (users: [User]) in
    // Handle result
}
```

**In your case**

```
var storiesData: [Story] = []

fetchData(urlString: "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808") { (stories: [Story] in
    storiesData = stories
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like great advice! When I call the function, how would I do the equivalent of `self.storyData = response.results` in my original example?

Comment: Updated my answer @KingTim

Comment: Thanks for that! How would `stories: [Story]` work there? Did you mean `storyData` instead of `stories`? I'm trying to get the data in my `storyData` array right? Would I set `self.storyData = stories` when calling the function?

Comment: The `stories: [Story]` will be the returning objects from your call. For instance, if you want to put the returning result in your `storyData` array all you need to do in the completion block is `storyData = stories`. Glad that I could help! @KingTim

Comment: Sorry, I ninja-edited after I posted that follow up comment - I tried exactly that that the table view I'm populating is coming up empty.

Comment: Make sure to reload the `tableView` once you get the new data. I'll edit the answer once more and you'll see @KingTim

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182316/discussion-between-jacob-ahlberg-and-kingtim).

Comment: So I think what I was missing was the `.resume()` after the URLSession. However once adding that I get the error `"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Check out our chat for the answer :) @KingTim

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7653367/jacob-ahlberg)'s answer I recommend to return also a possible error.

To keep the generic layout declare an – also generic – enum as return type

```
enum FetchResult<T> {
    case success(T), failure(Error)
}
```

and return `FetchResult` with the passed static type

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (FetchResult<T>) -> Void) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {completion(.failure(error!)); return } 
        do {
            let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(object))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

and use it

```
let jsonUrl = URL(string: "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=••••••••••••••••••:1:73741808")!

fetchData(url: jsonUrl) { (result : FetchResult<TopStoriesResponse>) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let object): print(object) // do something with object
    case .failure(let error): print(error) // handle the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer vadian - with this approach I'm still using my `storyData` array like before, correct? Once I have the object in the `.success` case, would I be setting `self.storyData = object`?

Comment: @KingTim Yes, exactly.

Comment: Just tried it out and I'm getting an error `Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController.TopStoriesResponse' to type '[ViewController.Story]'`. Will I need to change the way I set up the structs, or this a separate issue? These are the structs: https://pastebin.com/zDgan2BK

Comment: Please **read** the code. The returned `object` is the `TopStoriesResponse` object and the `[Story]` array is in the `results`  property. Actually it's lke in your question and in Jacob's answer.